# Upload video taken with iphone camera with PUT method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rest, video, upload

How can i upload a video taken with the camera or contained in the phone memory?
I need to upload it using a PUT method.

Thank you

Code for photo uploading:

```
- (void)uploadPhoto:(NSData *)data
{
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Date" value:timeStamp];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Auth" value:signature];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Client" value:apiClient];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:apiAccept];

[request addRequestHeader:@"USER" value:userHeader];

[request appendPostData:data];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
// Use when fetching text data
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"%@",responseString);

// Use when fetching binary data
NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
NSLog(@"%@",responseData);
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
NSError *error = [request error];
NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

none of the 3 methods at the end are called after i make this request.
Please help me.
Regards,

response string:

```
|?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?|
|error|
    |code|InvalidParameter|/code|
    |message|Invalid parameter specified (user)|/message|
|/error|
```

Comment: Does something need to retain the request? (I have no idea; perhaps ASIHTTPRequest is retained on a operation queue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using ASIHTTPRequest. Here is a sample:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request appendPostData:myVideoData];
[request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
```

Comment: myVideoData should be of NSData type?

Comment: i've tryed to upload an image, and i dont know why it doesnt work. I've loaded the code in the question.

Comment: Why are u using class method(+ uploadPhoto)? Use instance method.

Comment: hi again, i've used an instance method and now i get the error i've putted in the question

Comment: This error means two things:    
1) request(its mechanism) is working fine, coz your error is actually a response from the server. 
2) you'v got problems with 'User' parametr. Check all the data u are sending to the server.

Comment: thank for you're help. My user parameter had "\n" before numbers. That was my problem; now it works just fine.